# Confusion with useState, useEffect and useRef in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

My app is recipe search.  A search form and a submit button, and recipe results i get from API.
I have query state variable (declared with useState() ) I try to update it with onSubmit function on search form. So, my idea is : someone types something into search bar, and submits the query. MY onSubmit takes the current value and tries to set the query.
**Problem is, my queries are always delayed by 1 render. Default query is "chicken", so if i put in "cocoa" and hit submit, the API will give me results for chicken, and if i put "carrot" afterwar this, now i'll get results for "cocoa". Clearly i'm missing something because my state can't keep up with changes.**

And one extra question, if this happens because i don't call getRecipes function in my useEffect (instead, i just mention it). If i do call it, i get the errror :

Uncaught TypeError: destroy is not a function
**and** 
 index.js:1375 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

my code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import Recipe from "./Recipe";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const APP_ID = "c49a2xxx";
  const APP_KEY = "0fbf56f642af60a29a73841f1fbdcxxx";
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  //const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("chicken");
  const search = useRef();
  const exampleRequest = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`;
  useEffect(() => getRecipes, []);
  useEffect(() => getRecipes, [query]);
  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(exampleRequest);
    const data = await response.json();
    setRecipes(data.hits);
  };
  const submitSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search.current.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitSearch}>
        <input type="text" ref={search} />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>{" "}
      {recipes.map((recipe, key) => (
        <Recipe
          key={key}
          title={recipe.recipe.label}
          calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
          img={recipe.recipe.image}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the memory leak error might be caused by the two effects.

```
// Declared outside the component since it'll never change
const APP_ID = 'c49a2xxx';
const APP_KEY = '0fbf56f642af60a29a73841f1fbdcxxx';

const App = () => {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('chicken');
  const search = useRef();

  // useEffect(() => getRecipes, []); You don't need two effects that does the same task
  useEffect(() => {
    const getRecipes = async () => {
      // request url with params declared inside the function
      // to make sure you're using the updated state variable
      const exampleRequest = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`;
      const response = await fetch(exampleRequest);
      const data = await response.json();
      setRecipes(data.hits);
    };

    getRecipes();
  }, [query, APP_ID, APP_KEY]);

  const submitSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search.current.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitSearch}>
        <input type="text" ref={search} />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      {recipes.map((recipe, key) => (
        <Recipe
          key={key}
          title={recipe.recipe.label}
          calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
          img={recipe.recipe.image}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you want to learn more about aborting interrupted fetches, here's an article I found useful.

https://itnext.io/how-you-can-abort-fetch-request-on-a-flight-830a639b9b92